# How to understand Google reCaptcha Sessions Completed chart

Tags: recaptcha

Google reCAPTCHA has two Analytics charts: "**Requests Passed & Failed**" and "**Sessions Completed**". The first one seems to show that there's minimum/no failures with people passing reCAPTCHA, while the second one implies that on some days, **some 90% of attempts to pass reCAPTCHA fail**.

How am I supposed to read/understand these charts? Are my users failing at 90% rate or is all well?

[image: reCAPTCHA Analytics]